# Combinatorial proof for a Stirling identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

I am asked to use combinatorial proof to prove a Stirling identity:

$${n+1\brack m} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n-k\brack m-1} n^{\underline{k}}$$

Basically I know that the LHS is the number of permutations of an $n+1$ set with $m$ cycles, but I really don't know how to get the LHS. I fail to visualize this! Any help will be much appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: First pick the cycle that contains $n+1$; then draw the rest of the proverbial owl.

Comment: Do you mean to say $$\binom {n+1}{m}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n-k}{m-1}\binom {n}{k}$$

Comment: No it's a stirling cycle

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the RHS is easily interpreted as the number of permutations of $n+1$ into $m$ cycles.

Now consider the cycle that contains the element $n+1$ and consists of $k+1$  elements (in toto), there will be $m-1$ other cycles containing $n-k$ elements
\begin{eqnarray*}
\underbrace{(\cdots)\cdots (\cdots)}_{n-k \text{ elements in } m-1 \text{ cycles}} (n+1 \cdots)
\end{eqnarray*}
the last $k$ elements of the last cycle can be chosen in $n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)=n^{\underline{k}}$ ways and the first $k$ cycles can be chosen in ${n-k \brack m-1}$ ways. Now observe that $k$ can range over $1 ,\cdots ,n$ so
$$ {n+1 \brack m} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n-k \brack m-1} n^{\underline{k}}. $$